# Serve static files from a CDN rather than Flask in production

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In my Flask app I serve the static assets through the app in the dev env, but I'd like to use a CDN in production.  Every asset is loaded in a template called `base.html`, so I guess the easiest solution is to pass a variable to the render function and use it in the template like:

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/main.js"></script>
```

Normally it would be an empty string in the dev env, and the cdn url in production. I'd like to avoid passing this `STATIC_URL` variable to every view.  I could make it work with

```
@bp.context_processor
def set_static_path():
    return dict(STATIC_URL='https://foo.bar.com')
```

But for me this seems a little hacky. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no need to change how you link to static files, you can still use `url_for('static', filename='myfile.txt')`. Replace the default static view with one that redirects to the CDN if it is configured.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
# or for python 2: from urlparse import urljoin
from flask import redirect

@app.endpoint('static')
def static(filename):
    static_url = app.config.get('STATIC_URL')

    if static_url:
        return redirect(urljoin(static_url, filename))

    return app.send_static_file(filename)
```

Whether you're on a dev machine or production, set the `STATIC_URL` config value to the CDN and requests for static files will be redirected there.

---

Redirects are relatively cheap, and are remembered by browsers. If you get to the point where performance is meaningfully affected by them, you can write a function that links directly when using the CDN.

```
@app.template_global()
def static_url(filename):
    static_url = app.config.get('STATIC_URL')

    if static_url:
        return urljoin(static_url, filename)

    return url_for('static', filename=filename)
```

The `template_global` decorator makes the function available in all templates.  Use it instead of `url_for` when you need urls for static files.

---

There may be a Flask extension that does this for you already. For example, [Flask-S3](https://flask-s3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides a `url_for` that serves static files from AWS S3.

Answer (score 4):

This flask cdn [integration guide](https://www.keycdn.com/support/flask-cdn-integration-guide/) may be worth taking a read through. Basically you can install the [Flask-CDN extension](https://github.com/libwilliam/flask-cdn) and define your CDN URL within your app.py file like so:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.cdn import CDN

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CDN_DOMAIN'] = 'cdn.yourdomain.com'
CDN(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using [Flask Assets](https://flask-assets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and Flask-CDN.  I found that Flask-CDN was trying and failing to generate timestamps for each asset.  Upon failure it would revert to relative URLs.

Adding `app.config['CDN_TIMESTAMP'] = False` fixed the issue.