# Serve static files locally when a CDN fails

Tags: javascript, python, web-deployment, fallback

I currently am working on a Flask web app which serves static files using a CDN. However if the CDN fails I want to serve the file using the copy stored in the local directory.

ASP.NET has a nifty feature to achieve the same. If cloudflare.com is down, the app serves the local copy of the static file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.18.1/select.min.css"
                  asp-fallback-href="~/lib/angular-ui-select/dist/select.css"
                  asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
```

I was wondering if I could get the same functionality in Flask.

#### I've read and considered the following:-

- [Appending Script Tags](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx)

The problem I found with this approach is that I can only use it for JavaScript. There is no way to get it to work for images and CSS files. Moreover it's not something that we'd naturally do. I will be done with this internship soon and somebody else will have to go through the mess.

- [Serve static files from a CDN rather than Flask in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35824412/serve-static-files-from-a-cdn-rather-than-flask-in-production)

This gives a few pointers and is will be handy when we run browser tests. We can serve local copies when we run the tests. However there isn't a way to switch in case the CDN fails.

Thanks :)

Comment: I've checked how the ASP tag is implemented (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1580) and it looks like an output is pure JS so you may use it.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Will try writing a Python function that will do the same in the resultant template. You've given me a great pointer as well. Next time I'll check repositories for issues/code and try finding out what happens underneath.

Comment: Colleagues at work think there could be an easier/cleaner way to implement it. A module that isn't very well known.

Comment: If you'll find it don't hesitate to answer your own question with the solution, so anyone with similar problem could use it.

Comment: Have decided to use Jinja and Python to write a function. That's the only way I see now. Will answer soon.