# Serving Images from Cloudfront for Flask site

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Flask site that will contain a lot of images therefore I want to use a CDN to serve them from a different place.

I would like to go with the easiest solution and avoid using the [Flask CDN](https://github.com/libwilliam/flask-cdn) library or anything that requires adding plus code into my `app.py` file since I don't want any complicated feature.

So my idea is that I will upload my images to CloudFront and make them available on urls like this:

```
http://images.mydomain.com/filename.jpg
```

Than just use the proper link in my Jinja template like this:

```
<img src="http://images.mydomain.com/{{filename}}.jpg" alt="Image">
```

Instead of the current version:

```
<img src="/static/images/{{filename}}.jpg"  alt="Image">
```

So my question is that is it proper solution? Can it cause any negative effects? My goal is to keep everything simple as possible with the best performance. I assume it's a legit solution, but this is the first time when I use CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Serving static media from a CDN is the intended approach for all web application frameworks like Flask and Django. Serving static media through these apps is considerably slower and consumes a lot more server resources.

This is a duplicate of [Serve static files from a CDN rather than Flask in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35824412/serve-static-files-from-a-cdn-rather-than-flask-in-production)